# File-not-found-Error when building/runing my very dockerfile that should start a batch-file

Tags: windows, docker, batch-file, build

Hi I am new to docker containers and want to build and run a simple container which should then start a small batchfile. I am using docker desktop. / win 10. Everything is located in the same directory:

*C:\DockerTestGUI\Versionen\Dockerrunsbatch*

This is my batch-File I want to run in the end:

[image]

This is my dockerfile, just 1 line since I do not have to copy anything from DockerHub:

[image]

I build my image like that :

```
docker build -t simpleimage
```

When I try to run my Image I get this "not-found-error" :

[image]

Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: You should COPY the file first.
And where is your build stage? can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong image `ubuntu:latest`. It will use to execute shell scripts `(*.sh)` not batch files.
For batch file execution you need Windows image.

Here's initial Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803

CMD C:\DockerTestGUI\Versionen\Dockerrunsbatch\TestMessage.bat && cmd
```

Here, I have changed image name and associated version.
I have used tag `1803` as my host system version is `Windows 10 (10.0.17134)`.

You can choose with your windows version and then apply relevant tag.
Tags are listed in this link : https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore

Comment: This does not work either. I get the message:pull access denied for windowsservercore, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: Refer Link : https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore
1. Windows os requires. Check version of your host system.
2. If you use Docker Desktop. Choose "switch to windows containers" option.
3. Choose right Tag from List of Tags provided on above link down. Please choose carefully. I have chosen "1803" TAG from tag list as my machine OS is Windows 10.
4. It will work like a charm. Do rightful configurations first.
One do yourself, Let me know any hurdles you face then.